Hook fail when creating a new branch in GitLab
we have a self-managed gitlab install with a very simple git pre-receive hook to check the commit message format:
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    if [ "$oldrev" -eq 0 ]; then
        #git rev-list $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/* | sed 's/^/\^/') "$newrev"
        commits=$(git rev-list $newrev --not --branches=*)
    else
        commits=$(git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev)
    fi
    ticket=false
    for commit in $commits; do
        message=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 $commit)
        if [[ $message =~ ^[Tt]icket\ [0-9]+ ]]; then
            ticket=true
            break
        fi
    done
    if ! $ticket; then
        echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: At least one commit must have a message that starts with Ticket followed by a space and the ticket number"
        exit 1
    fi
done
exit 0

It works perfectly if we clone a repository, create a new branch and then push it, but it fails if we use the gitlab web interface to create the new branch.
I didn't find any clue in the gitlab documentation, eventually I'm ok with skipping the check when we are creating a branch from the web interface, but how I can detect that?
